# Blender 2.91.2 : Face texture looking weird while using shade smooth

Tags: texturing, uv, faces

Good day,

I have trouble with texturing my first model. The textures looks "edgy" while using shade smooth.

[image]

I have tried recomputing normals, merging normals, redoing the mesh twice, but I always come back to a similar looking result.

Comment: could you share your file so we can take a closer look?  You can use this link: https://blend-exchange.com/             Alternatively, if your file is too big, you can upload it as a google drive link.

Comment: Is this a knife with faces on either side?

Comment: Hello,

Yes, it's a blade.  Here is the model:[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=dOAgPZaa" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/dOAgPZaa/)